# How can I find out the codec of a video I have exported from Premiere Pro?

Tags: codec

I've exported some videos from Premiere Pro after working on them, but I've forgotten what the codec of the video is. How can I find out the codec of the video? Thanks!

Comment: Use [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)

Comment: @Gyan I tried [the online version](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline) for both of the videos, but it told me `Codec ID: mp42 (mp42/mp41)` for both of them. It's supposed to tell me `H.264` or `HEVC/H.265` since those two are the only two codecs I ever use (and I totally remember that I used *one* of these two codecs for the videos). Any help with this? Thanks! P.S. If File Explorer could tell me something about the codec, that would've been great. Unfortunately, File Explorer can't tell me anything about the codec of the video.

Comment: You have to see the codec id in the video section, not general. The label 'Codec ID' in the general section should be called something else.

Comment: @Gyan OK, thanks! Actually, I just tried it, and it turns out I need to look at the `Format` label in the `Video` section. For the first one, it said `AVC`, and I don't know what that means. (However, I think I can faintly remember that I had used `H.264` for that video.) For the second one, it said `HEVC`. Thanks!

Comment: AVC = H.264 and HEVC = H.265.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) to get technical information for a media file.

The codec id in the video section will print the exact identifier stored in the file for that video stream. The format entry in the same section will print the formal name of that codec.

Comment: Thanks for adding this as an answer! I just noticed this as I was doing some other things earlier and couldn't check Stack Exchange.